# From where in libc source code, is open() getting linked?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, system-calls, libc

I basically need to customize few *linux* system call interfaces (say *sys_open*) for my purpose. I am very much aware of GNU Linker ld --wrap=*symbol* option and use that logic to alter the open() libc wrapper. Although that serves the purpose, I really want to know where in libc source codes, the actual implementation comes into play.

The following two places are my major suspects (Note that the *fcntrl.h* has just the declarations)

- GLIBC_DIR/io/open.c
- GLIBC_DIR/ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/generic/open.c

Sample Driver:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;

    if ((fd = open("sample.c", O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "file not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Concerned snippet:

```
main:
  401dd1:       bf 44 90 48 00          mov    $0x489044,%edi
  401dd6:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  401ddb:       e8 10 03 03 00          callq  4320f0 <__libc_open>

......
......

 __libc_open:
  4320f0:       83 3d 69 8e 28 00 00    cmpl   $0x0,0x288e69(%rip)        
  4320f7:       75 14                   jne    43210d <__open_nocancel+0x14>

__open_nocancel:
  4320f9:       b8 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%eax
  4320fe:       0f 05                   syscall
```

For simplicity, I had prepared all the libc sources executable  **statically**. Also was careful enough to make GCC rightly pick the custom libc.a. I tried adding a puts statement but the mentioned two source codes are NOT getting invoked at all. Taking a look at the assembly of executable [shown above], the *sys_open* call (0x2 in *__open_nocancel*) has been somehow placed in the executable.

So my question is the following:

- From where exactly in libc, the *open()*-related code logic magically come?
- How is the linker able to successfully hook the open() function when there is no function explicitly named open in libc source tree?

Answer (score 4):

> From where exactly in libc, the open()-related code logic magically come?

In comes from `sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S`

> How is the linker able to successfully hook the open() function when there is no function explicitly named open in libc source tree?

If you preprocess above source with correct `-DSYSCALL_SYMBOL=...`, you'll discover that there *is* a mention of `open` in the source.

Comment: Thank you for your pointer. At the moment I am just trying to put a puts() statement before actual open() gets invoked. Any pointers (other than ld wrap option) on how/where to put this in source code? I know that the original libc sources has some macro that boils down to an inline assembly syscall in mentioned file.

Comment: The file sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64/open64.c is empty due to which we reach the syscall template. Do you think adding logic here (just like xstat64.c) will execute the new logic and cause the actual sys_open